# Geometrically Integrating $R(x,\sqrt{Ax^2+Bx+C})$ & Motivating Euler Substitutions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I believe there is a way to geometrically interpret integrating $R(x,\sqrt{Ax^2+Bx+C})$, as a means to motivate the [Euler substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution), in terms of

> "...expressing the coordinates of a point upon a conic $y^2 = Ax^2+Bx+C$ by means of
> rational functions of a parameter. It can be seen geometrically that this is possible,. For, if a secant $y - b = t(x - a)$ be drawn through any point $(a,b)$ on the conic, the coordinates of the second point of intersection of the secant with the conic are given by equations of the first degree, and are therefore rational functions of $t$".
>
> [Goursat - Page 215](https://archive.org/stream/coursemathanalys01gourrich#page/n230/mode/1up)

Can anyone parse this for me? I don't really see how this shows the second point of intersection is a rational function of the first degree.

This interpretation allows one to geometrically see that if the quadratic has imaginary roots, $A > 0$ and so this immediately implies the quadratic is a hyperbola. Therefore, geometrically, we see our 'Euler substitution' simply must be $y = \sqrt{A}x + t$, a straight line parallel to an asymptote of the hyperbola, and because it's an asymptote it cuts the hyperbola at the point

$$x = \frac{C-t^2}{2\sqrt{A}t-2B}, y = t+\sqrt{A}\frac{C-t^2}{2\sqrt{A}-2B}.$$

Similarly, if $A < 0$ the conic simply must be an ellipse, otherwise the quadratic is negative, and so geometrically we see we should substitute $y=t(x-a)$, the moving secant cutting the conic.

I believe this is an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786784/motivation-behind-euler-substitution-in-integrals), however I'd like somebody to parse all this out in a clearer form for us all to read, i.e. to make some of it more concrete and mathematical.

If one is masochistic enough, they could relate it to [this interesting post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537/toward-integrals-of-rational-functions-along-an-algebraic-curve) also, but that's not necessary, thank you

Comment: In your quoted paragraph the letters $a,b$ seem to be doing two different jobs.

Comment: Apologies, fixed.

Comment: Your answer seems perfectly clear to me. So I dont quite understand what more are you looking for ?